# Row reducing preserving characteristic polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra

I am working on an exercise in Aluffi which asks to calculate the characteristic polynomial of $$\begin{pmatrix} 6 &-10&-10\\3&-5&-6\\-1&2&3\end{pmatrix}.$$ Initially, I row reduced to $$\begin{pmatrix} 1&-2&-3\\0&1&3\\0&0&2\end{pmatrix}$$ and it is clear that the characteristic polynomial of the latter matrix is $(t-1)^2(t-2)$.

Then I thought: "Wait, the characteristic polynomial is invariant for similar matrices, but row operations don't necessarily preserve similarity."

So I instead did the calculation for the characteristic polynomial keeping the matrix as is, but then I still got $(t-1)^2(t-2)$. What happened here? Did I just get lucky?

Comment: How? Row operations do not even preserve the trace in general.

Comment: Sorry, I am being silly! I misread.

Comment: Is it somehow obvious that these two matrices are similar to the diagonal matrix you mention?

Comment: @DietrichBurde the original matrix is diagonalizable but the second one is not.  So the two matrices happen to have the same characteristic polynomial *but are not similar*.

Comment: @user8675309 Sorry, I have misread the question. The first matrix is similar to $diag(1,1,2)$, yes.